# Looking for an article/short story about two astronauts returning from space and realizing they've peaked

Tags: story-identification

It's about two astronauts who return from space and they realize that the they've already done the most important thing in their lives, they come to understand that their life is subpar besides their achievement in space.

It was published, within the last 10 years for sure, in a really small magazine or something and may or may not be available online. The author has published around five works since this. I think this was his first published work.

Comment: Is the story science fictional?

Comment: I know such a story from the 1970s, when this kind of story still made sense (todays astronauts know that they have a long career in front of them, and that they may even get back into space). As a subject for a contemporary short story this seems strangely anachronistic.